# How to disable usage of public maven repo

Tags: maven, repository, artifactory

I've setup a maven repository(Artifactory) in my LAN which has no internet access. I've also change my maven settings.xml to use this internal repo only. However when I try to create a maven project, it still try to access the public repo(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) for some downloads. Where has I done wrong?

For example, when I perform the following:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=demo.john -DartifactId=struts2demo 
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts 
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-starter 
    -DinteractiveMode=false
```

there is the following waring reported:

```
... ...
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: repo1.mavne.org
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared. ...
    ... ...
```

Sometimes the it build successfully with this waring, but sometime it won't.

Below is my maven's settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>central</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>my-company-repo</id>
      <name>A maven repo in local network</name>
      <url>http://my.internal.server/artifactory/repo<url>
    </mirror>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>artifactory</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://my.internal.server/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://my.internal.server/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://my.internal.server/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://my.internal.server/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: It looks like your settings.xml is correct (you generated it from Artifactory, didn't you?).
For some reason your Maven ignores those settings. Where did you put that file?

Comment: Use "mvn -s /path/to/settings.xml" to be sure you're using the correct file.

Comment: What you need is mirror go through the following link for more details http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html.

Comment: @JBaruch yes, the settings.xml is generated from Artifactory with some customization. It is in the default maven installation directory(<maven-root>/conf/settings.xml).

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I've tried adding the settings.xml explicitly on the commandline, still no luck.

Comment: @Karthikeyan Adding mirrors part doesn't help. The warning is still there.

Comment: Do you have the archetype org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-starter in your Artifactory if not thats the problem.

Comment: try using the [help:effective-settings](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-settings-mojo.html) goal to display the calculated settings as XML for this project. Maybe this can reveal some new information

Comment: @Karthikeyan Is that the builtin behavior of the maven ? I have not kept all the version of the archetype **struts2-archetype-starter** in my internal repo indeed. I thought it will pick another version instead or simply report an exception, instead of querying the official maven repo on the internet.

Comment: @drorb I'll try that and report progress here later.